# Exchange Rate return in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

```
require 'json'
require 'date'

module Exchange
  file = File.read('./data/data.json')
  data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

  def self.rate(date, from_currency, to_currency)
    date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    raise 'That date does not exist' unless data_hash[date]

    data_hash[date][to_currency] / data_hash[date][from_currency]
  end
end
```

This method must return the exchange rate between `from_currency` and `to_currency` on `date` as a float.

I have included a JSON file of currency exchange rates which are based upon the Euro. I need to  use this as your source of currency exchange rates

Also, the format of file can be anything other than json in future. and it should support different currency other than Euro as well. (I dont know how would i do this)

the json file looks like this:

```
{
  "2018-12-11": {
    "USD": 1.1379,
    "JPY": 128.75,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.845,
    "DKK": 7.4641,
    "GBP": 0.90228,
    "HUF": 323.4,
    "PLN": 4.2983,
    "RON": 4.6557,
    "SEK": 10.297,
    "CHF": 1.1248,
    "ISK": 140.2,
    "NOK": 9.7038,
    "HRK": 7.3943,
    "RUB": 75.5225,
    "TRY": 6.1295,
    "AUD": 1.5778,
    "BRL": 4.4417,
    "CAD": 1.5239,
    "CNY": 7.8498,
    "HKD": 8.8934,
    "IDR": 16625.0,
    "ILS": 4.2691,
    "INR": 81.8215,
    "KRW": 1284.17,
    "MXN": 23.0209,
    "MYR": 4.7615,
    "NZD": 1.6526,
    "PHP": 60.009,
    "SGD": 1.5617,
    "THB": 37.317,
    "ZAR": 16.2903
  },
  "2018-12-10": {
    "USD": 1.1425,
    "JPY": 128.79,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.866,
    "DKK": 7.4639,
    "GBP": 0.90245,
    "HUF": 323.15,
    "PLN": 4.2921,
    "RON": 4.6502,
    "SEK": 10.333,
    "CHF": 1.1295,
    "ISK": 140.0,
    "NOK": 9.6885,
    "HRK": 7.387,
    "RUB": 75.8985,
    "TRY": 6.0499,
    "AUD": 1.5842,
    "BRL": 4.4524,
    "CAD": 1.5218,
    "CNY": 7.8967,
    "HKD": 8.9283,
    "IDR": 16671.36,
    "ILS": 4.2642,
    "INR": 82.7284,
    "KRW": 1287.42,
    "MXN": 23.132,
    "MYR": 4.7671,
    "NZD": 1.6581,
    "PHP": 60.367,
    "SGD": 1.5667,
    "THB": 37.525,
    "ZAR": 16.3463
  },
  "2018-12-07": {
    "USD": 1.1371,
    "JPY": 128.36,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.851,
    "DKK": 7.4641,
    "GBP": 0.89085,
    "HUF": 323.5,
    "PLN": 4.2895,
    "RON": 4.6485,
    "SEK": 10.2665,
    "CHF": 1.1299,
    "ISK": 139.5,
    "NOK": 9.697,
    "HRK": 7.3913,
    "RUB": 75.885,
    "TRY": 6.0619,
    "AUD": 1.5766,
    "BRL": 4.4358,
    "CAD": 1.523,
    "CNY": 7.8244,
    "HKD": 8.8866,
    "IDR": 16454.01,
    "ILS": 4.2545,
    "INR": 80.509,
    "KRW": 1278.67,
    "MXN": 23.1435,
    "MYR": 4.7372,
    "NZD": 1.6558,
    "PHP": 60.059,
    "SGD": 1.5583,
    "THB": 37.359,
    "ZAR": 16.0673
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I am not understanding of using some ruby gems or how would I calculate the exchange rate.

Comment: 1) parse the JSON file
2) convert the date param to the same string format you see in the JSON
3) lookup the from_currency to EUR rate
4) lookup the EUR to to_currency rate
5) calculate

try to solve the problem and come back if you have more question and can show us what you've tried and what did not work. We do not solve homework here :-)

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) remove "but other sources might not be JSON and may not be based on the EUR.", as there is no way to deal with such an open-ended statement; 2) write, "The following is an example of a hash read from a JSON file."; 3) Make the hash a valid Ruby object by changing `} ....` to `}}` and assign a variable to the hash (e.g., `ex_rates = {"2018-12-11": {...}}`) so that readers can refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it; and 4) state whether it's a homework problem. If it is SO rules require you to describe efforts you've made to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, i tried something this

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (copy those 3 files)

**`exchange.rb`**

```rb
require 'json'

module Exchange
  @rates = JSON.parse(File.read('rates.json'))

  def self.rate(date, from_currency, to_currency)
    rates = @rates[date]                     # get rates of given day
    from_to_eur = 1.0 / rates[from_currency] # convert to EUR
    from_to_eur * rates[to_currency]         # convert to target currency
  end
end
```

**`test_script.rb`**

```rb
require_relative 'exchange.rb'
require 'date'

target_date = Date.new(2018,12,11).to_s
puts "USD to GBP: #{Exchange.rate(target_date, 'USD', 'GBP')}"
puts "USD to JPY: #{Exchange.rate(target_date, 'PLN', 'CHF')}"
puts "DKK to CAD: #{Exchange.rate(target_date, 'PLN', 'CHF')}"
```

**`rates.json`**

```
{
  "2018-12-11": {
    "USD": 1.1379,
    "JPY": 128.75,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.845,
    "DKK": 7.4641,
    "GBP": 0.90228,
    "HUF": 323.4,
    "PLN": 4.2983,
    "RON": 4.6557,
    "SEK": 10.297,
    "CHF": 1.1248,
    "ISK": 140.2,
    "NOK": 9.7038,
    "HRK": 7.3943,
    "RUB": 75.5225,
    "TRY": 6.1295,
    "AUD": 1.5778,
    "BRL": 4.4417,
    "CAD": 1.5239,
    "CNY": 7.8498,
    "HKD": 8.8934,
    "IDR": 16625.0,
    "ILS": 4.2691,
    "INR": 81.8215,
    "KRW": 1284.17,
    "MXN": 23.0209,
    "MYR": 4.7615,
    "NZD": 1.6526,
    "PHP": 60.009,
    "SGD": 1.5617,
    "THB": 37.317,
    "ZAR": 16.2903
  },
  "2018-12-10": {
    "USD": 1.1425,
    "JPY": 128.79,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.866,
    "DKK": 7.4639,
    "GBP": 0.90245,
    "HUF": 323.15,
    "PLN": 4.2921,
    "RON": 4.6502,
    "SEK": 10.333,
    "CHF": 1.1295,
    "ISK": 140.0,
    "NOK": 9.6885,
    "HRK": 7.387,
    "RUB": 75.8985,
    "TRY": 6.0499,
    "AUD": 1.5842,
    "BRL": 4.4524,
    "CAD": 1.5218,
    "CNY": 7.8967,
    "HKD": 8.9283,
    "IDR": 16671.36,
    "ILS": 4.2642,
    "INR": 82.7284,
    "KRW": 1287.42,
    "MXN": 23.132,
    "MYR": 4.7671,
    "NZD": 1.6581,
    "PHP": 60.367,
    "SGD": 1.5667,
    "THB": 37.525,
    "ZAR": 16.3463
  },
  "2018-12-07": {
    "USD": 1.1371,
    "JPY": 128.36,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.851,
    "DKK": 7.4641,
    "GBP": 0.89085,
    "HUF": 323.5,
    "PLN": 4.2895,
    "RON": 4.6485,
    "SEK": 10.2665,
    "CHF": 1.1299,
    "ISK": 139.5,
    "NOK": 9.697,
    "HRK": 7.3913,
    "RUB": 75.885,
    "TRY": 6.0619,
    "AUD": 1.5766,
    "BRL": 4.4358,
    "CAD": 1.523,
    "CNY": 7.8244,
    "HKD": 8.8866,
    "IDR": 16454.01,
    "ILS": 4.2545,
    "INR": 80.509,
    "KRW": 1278.67,
    "MXN": 23.1435,
    "MYR": 4.7372,
    "NZD": 1.6558,
    "PHP": 60.059,
    "SGD": 1.5583,
    "THB": 37.359,
    "ZAR": 16.0673
  }
}
```

When you run `test_script.rb` you should be able to see the exchange rates. I hope this works for you, but be aware that this only covers the JSON case. Let me know if it worked and I have to agree with @pascal_betz, in the future please provide more info what you already tried and what actually failed or what specifically you faild to do. But welcome to stackoverflow, definately keep posting, I know it can be discouraging in the beginning! ;)

Comment: This assumes that "buy" and "sell" exchange rates are the same, which you must of course assume is true since you are given just use one set of rates, but it is a real-world issue.